# Get key from datalist in Form.Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I get from the API a json, with a list of each staff member:

```
const MOCK_STAFF = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Jhon Doe",
    department: "HR"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jane Doe",
    department: "Research"
}, etc
```

Then they get mapped in a datalist `<option>`, inside a Form.Control component:

```
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>    
                            <Form.Control
                            name='staffName'
                            value={0}
                            list="namesList"
                            onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e)}/>
                        <Form.Label>Department</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control disabled
                            name=department
                            value={}    
                            />   
                
                        <datalist id="namesList">
                           {MOCK_DATA.map( (data) => (
                            <option key={data.id} value={data.department}>{data.name}</option>
                           ))}
                        </datalist>
                    </Form.Group>
```

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-t59e7z?file=/src/App.tsx

I would like the `onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e)}` to get the data-value of `<option key={data.id}` on form submit, and to make the *department* `Form.Control` to reference the value of `<option value={data.department}` in the datalist.  The 'key' id must not show to the user, it is used as a primary key on the database.

I have tried:

```
function onChangeHandler(e:React.SyntheticEvent) {
    
    console.log(e.target.key);
}
```

but "property key does not exist on event.target".  Nor I can use `document.getElementById();` with react.  How can I get the values 'key', 'value' and/or 'default-value` from a Form.Control with a datalist?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A Select?

Comment: I am trying to get the user to start typing a name, get a list of matching names, select one, and then autp-fill the department field.  Then, onSubmit, the ID goes to the api request to the database.  Thank you

Comment: I gues you need to retrieve it from the attributes list. `e.target.getAttribute('key')`. You may give it a try and let us know.

Comment: I get error: `Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)`

Comment: codesandbox link ?

Comment: How is your data.id different from data.department? Option attribute "value" should already be unique so just use it instead of key

Comment: data.id is an int, which is the primary key for the db.  I need to retrieve all 3 values when a user select one of the options on the datalist

Comment: Still don't understand why you would need all three values on form submit

Comment: so, there is no way to retrieve all 3 values from an `<option> with react?  with plain js you could just document.getElementById()

Comment: @AmanSadhwani Added the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-t59e7z?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I could not achieve this with `data-list`, but did so with `react-select`:

```js
type StaffOption = {
    label: string, value: number
}
const MOCK_DATA= [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Jhon Doe",
    department: "HR"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jane Doe",
    department: "Research"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Elizabeth meyer",
    department: "Operations"
}]

type NameOption = {value: number, label: string, department: string}
type NameOptions = Array<NameOption>

function AddNewRowModal(props:AddNewRowProps) {
    const [selectedStaffID, setSelectedStaffID] = useState(0);

    function onChangeHandler(option: OnChangeValue<StaffOption, false>, 
             actionMeta: ActionMeta<StaffOption>) {
        console.log(option);  //this returns all 3 values defined on type StaffOption
        if (option?.value !== undefined) {
            setSelectedStaffID(option.value!);
        }  
    }

    function BuildOptions (data:any[]) {
        var options:NameOptions = []
        data.forEach(element => {
            options.push({
            value: element.id!,
            label: (element.name),
            department: element.department});
        });
        return options;
   var nameOptions = BuildOptions(MOCK_DATA);
    return (
        <Modal
            show={props.showModal}
            backdrop="static"
            keyboard={false}
            onHide={() => props.closeModal()} >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Add new Entry</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                   <Select 
                    options={nameOptions}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler} />
                </Modal.Body>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button variant='primary'>Create Entry</Button>
                    <Button variant='danger' onClick={() => props.closeModal()}>Cancel</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
    );
}
```

And the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-thunder-28e85u?file=/src/App.tsx)